# Image compare or classification using Python

Tags: python

I am really not sure if I am looking for image classification or its called something, please help me understand my use case.

I have a set of images, lets call them "good" ones (or models) and then I have new/incoming images, from these new/incoming ones I have sort out which are matching/similar to "good" ones and discard that don't match the "good" ones.

Please give me some pointers to read/research to address this use case. I am fine exploring Python or any ready to use opensource software/program/script.

Comment: You could do feature detection/matching. See for example https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to go with PIL or openCV python libraries which will handle all image processing functionalities .

PIL - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

openCV - https://docs.opencv.org/master/